# A non-numeric value error php7

Tags: php7

Tengo este error en php7 exactamente en la linea 47, he buscado mucho en varias fuentes pero hasta ahora no se como arreglarlo.

Adjunto fragment de codigo:
[image: Error en linea 47]

Comment: Revisa este link de stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044127/warning-a-non-numeric-value-encountered  Al parecer tus datos que obtienes no son numericos

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de ayuda tu respuesta, ya arrelge el error, como marla la pregunta como slucionada?

Comment: Publica lo que hiciste para resolver tu pregunta en el área de respuestas y marcarla

Comment: Una consulta: qué IDE usas?

Comment: la ide es Sublime text3